# image upload using multer but image came from postman form-data via array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

```
{
"step":"services",
"servicesDescription": [
        { "serviceTitle":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
         "serviceIcon": abc.jpg },
        { "serviceTitle":"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
          "serviceIcon": abc.jpg }
      ],
"_id":"63b7c15f06501c1ea0729f24"
}
```

here my ques is how i pick serviceicon image and upload via multer????and store path again with serviceicon .please help me

Comment: could you share postman curl?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.